# How to Kosher sea water?

Tags: kashrut-kosher, kashering-kosherization, bugs, yoreh-deah, chulin-tractate

BH

After you separate the water from the salt if you want to take sea water from the ocean and drink it whats the process of filtering that you have to get to actually drink the water that the water be free of any bugs?

Comment: Like by reverse osmosis? How could there possibly be anything visible after that, maybe clarify.

Comment: I'd have thought that the desalination process would remove bugs anyway?

Comment: I don't think anyone has researched it.

Comment: The (potential) issue in New York is the Croton Reservoir, which is freshwater. Those who consider that a problem would require a very fine filter. Saltwater has to be desalinated, typically through distillation -- turn the water into vapor, then collect that vapor. The salt stays behind, as do all the bugs. So the water's kosher!

Answer (score 1):

If you process saltwater to separate the salt and water then you wont need to do anything further to remove bugs. In the unlikely event that there are (visible) bugs in the water you can filter it.